# Software RAID 10 Array Space Loss

Tags: centos, raid, software-raid

I purchased a dedicated server from a hosting company for a forum I am starting and the drives are configured as 4 x 64GB SSD's in a RAID 10 software array.

The total amount of space I was expected to be available was approximately 128GB, but for some reason I only have a bit under 110GB.

I have asked the provider about the missing space and they have said that it is just because of the constraints of using software RAID, but after doing a lot of research I can't find anything that would support this.

The system is `CentOS 6.6 kernel 2.6.32-042stab108.2`

Here is the data from the server:

All of the 4 disk are completely used to create RAID10 arrays on your disk, the total space available may differ in software RAID from hardware RAID. You can view the disk and raid status below.

```
[root@ ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid10] [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      511936 blocks super 1.0 [4/4] [UUUU]

md2 : active raid10 sda3[0] sdc3[2] sdd3[3] sdb3[1]
      89231360 blocks super 1.1 512K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 1/1 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sdd1[3] sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      16375808 blocks super 1.1 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>


[root@ ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 63.0 GB, 63023063040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7662 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002023a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        2040    16384000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2   *        2040        2104      512000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3            2104        7663    44648448   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 63.0 GB, 63023063040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7662 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004f2ab

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1        2040    16384000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2   *        2040        2104      512000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc3            2104        7663    44648448   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 63.0 GB, 63023063040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7662 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000369e8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1        2040    16384000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2   *        2040        2104      512000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3            2104        7663    44648448   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 63.0 GB, 63023063040 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7662 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00069960

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1        2040    16384000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd2   *        2040        2104      512000   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd3            2104        7663    44648448   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md1: 16.8 GB, 16768827392 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 4093952 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md2: 91.4 GB, 91372912640 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 22307840 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 1048576 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md0: 524 MB, 524222464 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 127984 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

***** NEW DATA Per Request from @frostschutz *****

```
[root@host ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md*

mdadm: /dev/md does not appear to be an md device
/dev/md0:
    Version : 1.0
Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:44 2015
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 511936 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
Used Dev Size : 511936 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 4
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
      State : clean 
Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

       Name : host.domain.com:0  (local to host host.domain.com)
       UUID : f9e0a41c:2c27ffe7:146a6a71:6bc894fe
     Events : 28

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
   1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
   2       8       34        2      active sync   /dev/sdc2
   3       8       50        3      active sync   /dev/sdd2
/dev/md1:
    Version : 1.1
Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
 Raid Level : raid1
 Array Size : 16375808 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
Used Dev Size : 16375808 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 4
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
      State : clean 
Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

       Name : host.domain.com:1  (local to host host.domain.com)
       UUID : ae2e2e67:dd9728e7:2d290b6f:78ecec69
     Events : 19

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
   1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   3       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
/dev/md2:
    Version : 1.1
Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
 Raid Level : raid10
 Array Size : 89231360 (85.10 GiB 91.37 GB)
Used Dev Size : 44615680 (42.55 GiB 45.69 GB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 4
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Intent Bitmap : Internal

Update Time : Sat Jun  6 22:04:51 2015
      State : active 
Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

     Layout : near=2
 Chunk Size : 512K

       Name : host.domain.com:2  (local to host host.domain.com)
       UUID : 61d27050:e5608a68:84646e94:aa6d0d0c
     Events : 96

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8        3        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda3
   1       8       19        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb3
   2       8       35        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc3
   3       8       51        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd3
```

***** Second request for @frostschultz *****

```
[root@host ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/sd*
/dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     32768000 sectors at         2048 (type fd)
Partition[1] :      1024000 sectors at     32770048 (type fd)
Partition[2] :     89296896 sectors at     33794048 (type fd)
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ae2e2e67:dd9728e7:2d290b6f:78ecec69
           Name : host.domain.com:1  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 32751616 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
     Array Size : 16375808 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
    Data Offset : 16384 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=16304 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 942ee69a:8ab0df94:d35c9128:8bfb7655

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 48294779 - correct
         Events : 19


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sda2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : f9e0a41c:2c27ffe7:146a6a71:6bc894fe
           Name : host.domain.com:0  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:44 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1023968 (500.07 MiB 524.27 MB)
     Array Size : 511936 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 1023872 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
   Super Offset : 1023984 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=104 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f1c6b25d:693eee98:2addb450:2aeb5c37

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 62a85b35 - correct
         Events : 28


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sda3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 61d27050:e5608a68:84646e94:aa6d0d0c
           Name : host.domain.com:2  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 89231360 (42.55 GiB 45.69 GB)
     Array Size : 89231360 (85.10 GiB 91.37 GB)
    Data Offset : 65536 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=65456 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : ba051f9d:ad1c1656:7fdc5bf1:397728fc

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 22:25:13 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : b3fae8fc - correct
         Events : 96

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     32768000 sectors at         2048 (type fd)
Partition[1] :      1024000 sectors at     32770048 (type fd)
Partition[2] :     89296896 sectors at     33794048 (type fd)
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ae2e2e67:dd9728e7:2d290b6f:78ecec69
           Name : host.domain.com:1  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 32751616 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
     Array Size : 16375808 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
    Data Offset : 16384 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=16304 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 8dd698b4:c8ad9ac0:a92fa8b1:be01b26c

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 2de8c5bb - correct
         Events : 19


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : f9e0a41c:2c27ffe7:146a6a71:6bc894fe
           Name : host.domain.com:0  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:44 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1023968 (500.07 MiB 524.27 MB)
     Array Size : 511936 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 1023872 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
   Super Offset : 1023984 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=104 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fe45fa24:a9b1b2e1:357894ce:0a25ae78

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : 31e5226f - correct
         Events : 28


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 61d27050:e5608a68:84646e94:aa6d0d0c
           Name : host.domain.com:2  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 89231360 (42.55 GiB 45.69 GB)
     Array Size : 89231360 (85.10 GiB 91.37 GB)
    Data Offset : 65536 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=65456 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3dc3c3bb:7d46da83:6bcffa25:71fb51e3

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 22:25:13 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 1c2c4774 - correct
         Events : 96

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     32768000 sectors at         2048 (type fd)
Partition[1] :      1024000 sectors at     32770048 (type fd)
Partition[2] :     89296896 sectors at     33794048 (type fd)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ae2e2e67:dd9728e7:2d290b6f:78ecec69
           Name : host.domain.com:1  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 32751616 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
     Array Size : 16375808 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
    Data Offset : 16384 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=16304 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 970f9254:c1498c69:ae75f67a:499e294e

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 21997d4e - correct
         Events : 19


   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : f9e0a41c:2c27ffe7:146a6a71:6bc894fe
           Name : host.domain.com:0  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:44 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1023968 (500.07 MiB 524.27 MB)
     Array Size : 511936 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 1023872 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
   Super Offset : 1023984 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=104 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1b64b17c:6b32f75a:2ea5e242:7fe886e8

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : e707b1bc - correct
         Events : 28


   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 61d27050:e5608a68:84646e94:aa6d0d0c
           Name : host.domain.com:2  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 89231360 (42.55 GiB 45.69 GB)
     Array Size : 89231360 (85.10 GiB 91.37 GB)
    Data Offset : 65536 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=65456 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 9d2d00a0:54582922:b6ff7c9f:d7a72861

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 22:25:13 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 9610a05c - correct
         Events : 96

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     32768000 sectors at         2048 (type fd)
Partition[1] :      1024000 sectors at     32770048 (type fd)
Partition[2] :     89296896 sectors at     33794048 (type fd)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : ae2e2e67:dd9728e7:2d290b6f:78ecec69
           Name : host.domain.com:1  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 32751616 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
     Array Size : 16375808 (15.62 GiB 16.77 GB)
    Data Offset : 16384 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=16304 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 094af00a:40bf3096:d675d62d:4f77b847

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : b10b066d - correct
         Events : 19


   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd2:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : f9e0a41c:2c27ffe7:146a6a71:6bc894fe
           Name : host.domain.com:0  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:44 2015
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1023968 (500.07 MiB 524.27 MB)
     Array Size : 511936 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 1023872 (500.02 MiB 524.22 MB)
   Super Offset : 1023984 sectors
   Unused Space : before=0 sectors, after=104 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b7c19d19:a8b7ca21:23c9259b:0ecaaa2f

    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 07:19:42 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset -8 sectors
       Checksum : ea2e9a19 - correct
         Events : 28


   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.1
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 61d27050:e5608a68:84646e94:aa6d0d0c
           Name : host.domain.com:2  (local to host host.domain.com)
  Creation Time : Fri Jun  5 05:05:32 2015
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 89231360 (42.55 GiB 45.69 GB)
     Array Size : 89231360 (85.10 GiB 91.37 GB)
    Data Offset : 65536 sectors
   Super Offset : 0 sectors
   Unused Space : before=65456 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 25151df4:f0c22a6f:fa9d3e43:d40295dd

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sat Jun  6 22:25:13 2015
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 575cebc3 - correct
         Events : 96

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
[root@host ~]#
```

***** UPDATE after feedback additional feedback: *****

Redo the system (I'm a from scratch kind of guy on a brand new box)

```
**Option 1)**
Boot : 512 MB on 4 drives in RAID 10 : 1GB
Swap : 8 GB on 4 drives in RAID 10   : 16 GB
/    : ~54 GB on 4 drives in RAID 10 : ~108 GB

**Option 2)**
Boot : 256 MB on 4 drives in RAID 10 : 512 MB
Swap : 8 GB on 4 drives in RAID 10   : 16 GB
/    : ~55 GB on 4 drives in RAID 10 : ~110 GB
```

Remaining question being, is Option 2 sufficient or should I go with Option 1 just to be conservative/safe?

Comment: `mdadm --detail /dev/md*` might help explain the sizes. `mdadm --examine /dev/sd*` should also include data offsets.

Comment: here is the output of the mdadm --detail /dev/md* (sorry if this is a message of comments, this forum software is really nothing like what I'm used to...

Comment: Ok, @frostschutz the only way I could see to add the data you requested was to update the main post, so I tried to separate the new data by starting each command with a ***** block hope that makes it clear enough.

Comment: @BentDreams Updating posts with new information to make them more complete is the way to work on this site. However we have revision history and using [edit], we can see what is changed. So there is no need to comment in the post about what was changed (at most you can ping the person requesting the info in a comment, as they don't get notified of posts being edited).

Comment: Thx @Anthon, if I understand you correctly, just update the post and then add a comment tagging the person/people that I want to update just to let them know that info has been added. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your drives aren't set up entirely as RAID10 devices. Each of your four drives is partitioned into three partitions, one containing approximately 16.8GB (I'm using [SI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) GBs here), one containing 524MB, and one containing 45.7GB.

The set of four 16.8GB partitions is assembled into `md1`, a 16.8GB RAID1 device (`md1: active raid1`; all four partitions are mirrored, so the total capacity is that of a single partition). The set of four 524MB partitions is assembled into `md0`, a 512MB RAID1 device. Finally, the set of four 45.7GB is assembled into `md2`, a 91.4GB RAID10 device.

As a result of all that, your total capacity is 91.4+0.5+16.8 = 108.7GB, instead of the 126GB you'd expect if everything was set up as RAID10 devices.

It is possible to convert a RAID1 with four devices to a RAID10, and `mdadm` supports this indirectly (as pointed out by [frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz)): it can "grow" a RAID1 array into a RAID0 array, then grow the RAID0 array into a RAID10 array. (Read the "grow mode" section of the `mdadm(8)` manpage.) If you do convert your two RAID1 arrays to RAID10 arrays, you'll end up with a total capacity of 91.4+0.5*2+16.8*2 = 91.4+1+33.6 = 126GB.

From your options I'd pick a variant of option 1:

- boot: 512 MB on 4 drives in RAID 1: 512MB
- swap: 8 GB on 4 drives in RAID 10: 16 GB
- /: ~54 GB on 4 drives in RAID 10: ~108 GB

simply because I don't know how well `grub` (or whatever bootloader you use) supports RAID10, and because a RAID1 partition can be used directly in a pinch, without `md` support.

Comment: It's merely a technicality, you have to RAID1 -> RAID0 -> RAID10. So it's two grow commands instead of one. (At least, with current `mdadm` and kernel; not sure about Centos 2.6.32).

Comment: Ah right, thanks; the `mdadm` manpage I read doesn't mention converting from RAID1 to RAID0.

Comment: So really my issue is that if the space was requested as a RAID 10 array, is this the way you would expect it to be configured in order to make the most redundant array, but accomodating the boot partition (512mb) and the swap versus the main data partition? I'm just not sure if I just need to accept the space lost or go back to the provider and tell them to set it up properly?

Comment: RAID1 for the boot partition makes sense. Swap on the other hand doesn't need mirroring at all; to get 16GB of swap I'd just use four 4GB partitions, perhaps configured in RAID0 if it improves performance. That would free 12GB per drive for data, so you'd get an extra 24GB in RAID10.

Comment: @StephenKitt swap needs mirroring too, if you expect the machine to continue running with a failed disk.

Comment: You're right, so four 8GB swap partitions in RAID10 would give 16GB capacity with the same resilience as the rest, and 8GB more per data partition resulting in 16GB more data storage.

Comment: Ok, for consistency sake, and to make sure that everything functions properly I think what I'm understanding is that a better layout is:

Comment: Ok, went back and added my understanding of the two options for layout at the end of main post. Really appreciate your feed back guys.

Comment: @BentDreams see my update.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt I had contacted the provider and requested something similar but they asked if I wanted the partitions more detailed, so / was broken up more.

Comment: (sorry for the multiple replies, the ENTER thing is still getting me and I went past the 5 minute edit limit) They ended up delivering the entire system as RAID 1 losing ~50% of all the space instead of just the ~512 MB for the /boot partition :-O At this point I'm going to get a refund for the server since they apparently are not able to simply deliver a machine, so I doubt they would be much use actually supporting it in the event of a critical system failure. I'll have to use your and @frostschutz's feedback on the next go-round. Thanks for the help and enjoy your week.

Comment: @BentDreams if it's not a managed server, the proper set-up is your responsibility.

Comment: From an operational standpoint I agree. In this case though the provider was responsible for the initial delivery of the system operationally ready for me to begin work with. When I requested information about connecting to the system using the KVM as well as any details of the system required to properly configure it in their network, I was told they would redo it because they were responsible for it. Either way, at the end of the day they proved that they would be worthless for future hardware and network troubleshooting and I've moved on.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons for the confusion here.

1. SSD drives are often advertised as "raw" capacity, which includes all the overprovisioning for faulty sectors. So a 64GB device might actually have only 60GB usable space.
2. Disks are specified in 10^n units, so 64GB is (64*10^9) bytes. Memory and computer users' frequent expectations are based around 2^m units, where 64GiB is (2^36) bytes.

If you look at the raw size of your disks as reported by `fdisk`, 63023063040 bytes, this is approximately 63GB or 58GiB.

On top of this, partitions are usually not started at the first disk sector, and are generally rounded off at a convenient boundary (if you've formatted with cylinders, it will be a complete number of cylinders. It's better to format SSDs by blocks or sectors). And then there's filesystem overhead, which is why `df -h` on a complete disk never matches the size claimed via `fdisk`.

Comment: Right, I saw the raw space vs the advertised space, which wasn't unexpected. I don't think any drives or disk really are the exact size that they sold as... Advertised sizes are really a marketing convenience ;)

Answer (score 1):

Stephen Kitt already answered your question properly, but since you mentioned 'constraints of using software RAID', there is one other issue that can waste a bit of space and that's the size of the RAID metadata.

In theory RAID metadata is really small, a few kilobytes at most.

In practice `mdadm` reserves quite a lot of space for its metadata. In your case it's `16384` sectors on `/dev/sd[abcd]1` and `65536` sectors on `/dev/sd[abcd]3`. So that's about `40MiB` wasted - per disk. The current version of `mdadm` reserves up to `262144` sectors. With several RAID partitions and many disks in a given RAID, it adds up. In my own setup it would take several gigabytes just for offsets.

The only reason it uses such large offsets is to make some grow operations more efficient, and every time you grow your RAID you lose a bit of the offset.

If you don't need this feature, you can specify `--data-offset=2048` at the time you create the RAID. That way the metadata will use `1MiB` offset for data alignment reasons.